# How to know *from macOS* if someone is already connected to a shared machine with Microsoft Remote Desktop Protocol Connection?

Tags: macos, remote-desktop

In the environment I work in, our customers often provide a shared Windows jumphost with only a single shared account with access only via Microsoft Remote Desktop Protocol. It is inconvenient to always ask whether someone is currently connected before connecting, so my question is: is there a way to check *from macOS* before / while connecting whether someone is currently using the connection?

This question has been asked (at least) twice before:

- [How to know if someone is already connected to a shared machine with Remote Desktop Connection?](https://superuser.com/q/343179/2571)
- [How to know if someone else is logged to a remote shared PC?](https://superuser.com/q/1035668/2571)

However, all answers to both of those questions assume that the client OS is Windows, whereas I am using the latest release version 10.7.6 (1972) of the official Microsoft Remote Desktop Client for macOS.

Note that there is no need to list all active sessions or all active users on the remote machine, which as I understand requires elevated user privileges on the remote machine. The only requirement is to know whether someone is currently logged into the same account I am currently trying to log into.

In other words: the goal simply to avoid accidentally kicking someone else off the machine. We sometimes use mouse recorders to automate long-running repetitive configuration tasks and someone might fire off one of those mouse recorder macros and then go to lunch or even go to sleep. It would be very annoying then to come back to the PC only to find that the macro was interrupted halfway through because someone else took control of the session.

In some cases, those credentials are even shared between different vendors, so it might not even be easily possible to coordinate access out-of-band.

Comment: If I understood right, you're asking how from *outside* a Windows computer to find out if there's an RDP connection to it? If I understood right, what other way to access that computer beside RDP is available?

Comment: @harrymc: For the sake of simplicity, let's assume "none" and if there is a particular way to do it which requires some other feature to be active on the remote PC, then by all means provide an answer saying so. But in general, assume that the personnel on-site is barely competent enough to activate the checkbox in the System → Remote Desktop menu. So, assume a default Windows 10 install with only that checkbox activated.

Comment: From what I understood from the answers to those other questions, they require additional privileges to list all the sessions and/or all the users. However, I don't know whether that is actually required, since I don't want to list other users, but only want to list "myself", if that makes sense.

Comment: These answers were for tests that are done *from inside the Windows RDP server*, in your case the jumphost. You are on the outside and can't use any of the suggestions, so it doesn't matter whether you are on Windows or Mac.

Comment: I think it is possible. I use a commercial software for Windows called Royal TS, and frequently connect to Windows servers (not Windows 10). One of the features in the app called Dashboard can show you who is currently connected to the server. In Windows Server, without buying any additional licenses, you can keep two remote connections open. So this dashboard view might tie into a specific feature that is only in Windows Server and not available in Windows 10. But, if it is not specific to the server version, then there is a way to find out who is remotely connected, before you connect.